# How apply machine learning code to ryu controller

Tags: machine-learning, controller, sdn, ryu

I am setting up SDN as follows

terminal 1:

```
sudo mn --topo=single,3 --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --mac --switch=ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

terminal 2:

```
ryu-manager ryu.app.simple_switch_13
```

terminal 3:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl show
sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 dump-flows s1
```

I want to add my machine learning that will detect a DDOS attack on SDN. How can I add it to the RYU controller so that every time I start RYU that code will run?

I am using preconfigures .ova machine.